# Assigning types to a range of integers using enum?

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

I have an array of indices [1 ... 20]. The first 4 elements of the indicesArray are linked to a file of a certain type (call it type A), the other 16 are linked to type B.

I shuffle the array at random. I now wish to extract 4 of the indices but at most only one of the 4 can be of type A.

I think I need to use the enum function here to define indices 1-4 as "type A" & indices 5-20 as "type B", then if I looked at e.g. the first element of my freshly randomised indicesArray[0] I could tell which type it is & act accordingly.

The way I've seen enum used from examples it goes something like:

```
enum category { typeA = 0, typeB };
```

Is it possible to assign indices 1-4 to typeA & the rest to typeB, or am I on the wrong track here? thanks in advance.

Edit to include code snippet

I tried to test this & ran into an error right away

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int* indices = malloc(20*sizeof(int));

for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

    indices[i] = i;

}

enum category {typeA, typeB};


enum category categoryForIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 1 && index <= 4) {
        return typeA;
    } else {
        return typeB;
    }
}

[pool drain];
return 0;

}
```

When i try to compile this I get the error "nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable", which usually happens when a second main gets thrown into the mix by accident, or someething like that. Any ideas?

Edit to include some code which shows how to put the solution into practice

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum category {typeA, typeB};

enum category categoryForIndex(int index) {
if (index >= 1 && index <= 4) {
    return typeA;
   } else {
    return typeB;
    }

}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int* indices = malloc(20*sizeof(int));

for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {

    indices[i] = i;

}


NSLog(@"index[0] is %i:", indices[16]);

enum category index;

index = indices[16];

switch (categoryForIndex(index)) {   //this tests to see what category 16 belongs to
    case typeA:
        NSLog(@"index is of type A");   
        break;
    case typeB:
        NSLog(@"index is of type B");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"index not valid");
        break;
}

 [pool drain];
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: beware indexes in C go from `0` to `N-1`, inclusive.

Comment: thanks pmg :) yes the array I refer to holds indices (which happen to start at 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off track. You cannot assign 1-4 a given enum. Enum constants have precisely one value, and only one. What you can do is use an enum to define two types, say `typeA` and `typeB` as you've already done, and then define a function that maps an index back to a type, e.g.

```
enum category categoryForIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 1 && index <= 4) {
        return typeA;
    } else {
        return typeB;
    }
}
```

Now you have a way to categorize your indexes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that makes sense, i tried it out & got an error I wasn't expecting - to do with nested functions. I've posted a little code snippet above.

Comment: @Octave1: That's because you've tried to define a function *within* the `main` function of your program. You need to move it outside (such as before the `main` function).

Comment: Great that worked very well, I've posted some code which shows how to check which category a given index belongs to, as it took me a little while to figure out, and might be useful to someone. Thanks again dreamlax & Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without first shuffling the array, so that you know the A's are always at the front:

```
#define IndexCount 20
#define ExtractCount 4
#define TypeACount 4

int indicesRemainingCount = IndexCount;
int indices[IndexCount] = { ... }; // your indices, first 4 are type A
int chosenIndices[ExtractCount]; // to be filled with random elements from indices, max one of type A

int minIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ExtractCount; ++i) {
    int j = minIndex + arc4random_uniform(indicesRemainingCount - minIndex);
    chosenIndices[i] = indices[j];
    if (j < TypeACount) {
        // Set minIndex so I won't pick another A.
        minIndex = TypeACount;
    } else {
        // Remove the chosen B so I don't pick it again.
        --indicesRemainingCount;
        indices[j] = indices[indicesRemainingCount];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is reasonable as long as you're willing to destructively modify the input array.

Comment: He said he wanted to shuffle it.  So he was going to either modify it or copy it.

Comment: By "destructively" I mean you're throwing away data about what was in the array to begin with. Rather than swapping cells, you're overwriting them. Granted, if you did change that to a swap, then it becomes equivalent to the shuffle case.